# orbit control: how to change the viewer-based method to object-based one

Tags: three.js

Orbit control is a viewer-based perspective control. 
I want to change the controls to a object-based one. Moreover I would like to pick a point and set it as the center/target of rotation.....how can I do it?

Comment: OrbitControls implements a Target-property, just use this.

Comment: So I can find the center of a 3d-object in my scene (as a THREE.Vector3()) and then set my control.target to that center?

Comment: I tried with 'var pos = my3dobj.position;
 myorbitcontrols.target = pos;' now it seems to be ok, but the pan doesn't work (well, it appears like I move other objects....)

Comment: Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: maybe create a Fiddle to better show your problems with the pan

Comment: Here the fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/bomastudio/w1gsv209/28/). Initially the cube rotate around it center (0,0,0). But if you zoom out and then pan, try to rotate the cube.....it will rotate around a new center or target out of the box. I want that, after panning and/or zooming the center of rotation is the box center, as to say "object-based rotation"

Comment: fiddle link gives me Error 404

Comment: sorry ![link](http://jsfiddle.net/bomastudio/g3ha1c57/)

Comment: I already got the initial problem but I thought you would present a fiddle with the possibility of the camera target being centered to the object. Because what I do not understand is what you mean with the panning does not work anymore

Comment: If I set 'controls.target = sphere.position;' pan doesn't work anymore, see the Fiddle.

Comment: cloning the vector does work for me, though, using sphere.position.clone()

Comment: ok, pan works but we are in the same initial "problem" (after panning the cube rotate around a point that isn't it center....

Comment: I made two images to explain better the question [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18236667/Schermata%20del%202014-10-09%2011%3A14%3A33.png) and  [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18236667/Schermata%20del%202014-10-09%2011%3A14%3A44.png)

Comment: diving deeper into OrbitControls.js I can observe that when I pan the camera (and that's ok) moves in the opposite direction. And the target (it's coordinates) moves in the same exact way. But the target is always in the center of the screen, and the new rotation is around this point (it isn't the "old" center).

Comment: of course you will have to recenter the target after panning. This is how orbit controls work. if you want to have the camera keep its direction but rotate around a given position, you will have to edit some stuff to make this happen I guess.

Comment: Any way to do this? I'm trying without success.....

Comment: onMouseUp for the pan-click and then do "target = obj.pos".  
This would of course re-focus the camera instantly.

Comment: I have to change the OrbitControls.js?

Comment: no, i think you can also add an event listener somewhere else, just give it a try onMouseUp from right-click (pan)

Comment: @mrdoob suggested to modify the `OrbitControls.js`.....my knowledge of javascript is no so deep to let me able to do it alone....please I need some sugggestions...

Comment: in Orbitcontrols, find the function onMouseUp( /* event */ ) {}. and in there, you will need to get the object position and just do target = obj.pos().  

To get the obj.pos(). you will have to add some kind of variable to orbitcontrols to make the position accessible from within orbitcontrols.

Comment: Suppose that my object is always positioned on the (0,0,0), so that obj.position is fixed. If I set 'scope.target = obj.position' every time I rotate with middle button after a pan, the camera looks on (0,0,0) and moves far away.